# My Java System.out.print's seem to overlap slightly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been working on this today; it's Java code so you can: enter amount of students, enter their first name, surname, percentage and then it prints out what that percentage is (pass/distinction) etc.

But for some little reason, for the first entry only, the first and surname prompt both appear at the same time therefore first name gets overridden by surname and no first name for the first student can even be inputted.

Can you spot the problem? Thank you.

```
//imports scanner class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        // new scanner called sc
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

        // start off by asking:
        System.out.print("How many students? ");
        // typed in number = number of students
        int count = sc.nextInt();
        // Line break 
        System.out.print("\n");

        // new strings for name/grade and int for percentage
        String fname[] = new String[count]; 
        String lname[] = new String[count]; 
        int percent[]  = new int[count]; 

        System.out.println("A-Z for Name & 0-9 for Percentages Only\n"); 

        // if there's input - add the info in 
        for (int i=0; i<count;i++){ 

            // enter first name
            System.out.print("Enter first name: "); 
            fname[i] = sc.nextLine(); 

            // enter surname
            System.out.print("Enter last name: "); 
            lname[i] = sc.nextLine(); 

            // enter percent
            System.out.print("Enter percentage: "); 
            percent[i] = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        }

        // print out some text for information
        System.out.println("\nThe following information displays the students full name, percentage & their grade.");   

        // and print them on screen
        for (int i=0; i<count;i++) { 
            System.out.print("\nStudent - " + fname[i] + " " + lname[i] + " received " + percent[i] + "%."); 

            if (percent[i] >= 00 && percent[i] <= 39)   {System.out.print(" That's a Fail.");}
            if (percent[i] >= 40 && percent[i] <= 64)   {System.out.print(" That's a Pass.");}
            if (percent[i] >= 65 && percent[i] <= 84)   {System.out.print(" That's a Merit.");}
            if (percent[i] >= 85 && percent[i] <= 100)  {System.out.print(" That's a Distinction.");}
            if (percent[i] > 100)                       {System.out.print(" This percentage is too high? please try again.");}
            if (percent[i] < 0)                         {System.out.print(" This percentage is negative? please try again.");}

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: well are you sure what values are you writing into your arrays?? try printing every value you read with  sc.nextLine();  to be sure

Comment: By using `else if` you can avoid needing the `&&` to check the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the first scanner nextInt() entry. You enter this data by entering a number and pressing enter. But the nextInt just reads the integer and the return carriage still remains on the input. When the code proceeds the next scanner nextLine() method will read that return carriage immediatly as it is still pending on the input. Leaving the firstname empty  during the process. To avoid this you could do a call to nextLine() before the loop.

You could also avoid this by always using nextLine() and parsing the resulting string to an integer in the first question.

Comment: Instead of `int count = sc.nextInt();` try `int count = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());`

Comment: Just added a "sc.nextLine();" before the loop. Cheers Juru! how did I miss that.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("How many students? ");
    // typed in number = number of students
    int count = sc.nextInt();
    **sc.nextLine();**
    // Line break 
    System.out.print("\n");
```

You can add sc.nextLine(); after your nextInt() call to get rid of the extra newline character that way you will start with a fresh line when you ask for the name.